# How to programmatically access default alert time for calendar events?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, eventkit

In recent iOS versions, users may select a default alert time that will be used for all newly-created events (by going to `Settings --> Mail, Contacts, Calendars --> Calendars / Default Alert Times`, see http://www.imore.com/how-edit-calendar-defaults-alerts-and-sync-settings-iphone-and-ipad#calendar-alerts ).

I am looking through EventKit documentation and can't find a way to read this setting programmatically. I've tried creating a dummy event with `[EKEvent eventWithEventStore:]` and reading its `alarms` property, but it doesn't seem to have the default alarm set until I save the event. Of course, I could save the event, read its `alarms` property and then delete it right away, but it seems like an ugly solution.

What's the proper way to access this setting from code?